# Puppetteer different behaviour based on ip location

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

Is it possible that my code works with an IP based in italy, but doesn't with an IP based in Germany? Looks like it is, I can't seem to find the same selector if I access Facebook from italy as if I access Facebook from Germany... Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's entirely possible, lots of sites tailor content by location.

You could test this with a VPN that allows to to specify client location. Try switching the location between Germany and Italy and you should be able to replicate this behaviour.